# Word order question (在一起 and 合作)

Tags: grammar, word-order

I am learning Chinese on my own and I find myself getting the word order wrong on some sentences.

For example:
我們在一起合作很多年了
I sometimes mistakenly use this word order:
我們合作在一起很過年了

I realize this is a very basic question, but could somebody explain why 在一起 must come before 合作 in this sentence?

Also, what is the grammatical rule called, if I want to read up on this?  In other words, what do I search for in order to find the grammar rule that applies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

一起/ 在一起 means 'together'(adv)

In English, it goes after the verb; In Chinese, it goes before the verb

Example:

[一起]看電視 - watch TV. [together]

[一起]洗澡 - bath [together]

[在一起]看電視 - watching TV. [together]

[在一起]洗澡 - bathing [together]

> 我們在一起合作很多年了

在一起 = together

合作 = work together

'*together*' in 'We have worked together for many years *together*' sounds redundant

It is better not to use the adverb 在一起 (together) in this context:

> 我們合作了很多年了 - We have worked together for many years

or change 合作 to 工作(work)

> 我們在一起工作很多年了 - We have been working together for many years

Comment: thank you for a comprehensive answer.  Re. redundancy, I agree, but it is an example sentence from an online Chinese course, so I thought it was normal (a bit like doubling up certain words, e.g. 好好休息).  I am glad that you clarified this point.

Comment: Agree. 在一起合作 is wordy.

Answer (score 0):

According to Chinese logic, it can be simply and rudely understood as
because， only "together" then  "work together"
So "together" first, then "together"

Comment: According to logic, if you are working together, you are together already

Answer (score 0):

Both sentences are acceptable.

- 我們 在一起合作 很多年了 - We together have cooperated for many years.
- 我們 合作在一起 很多年了 - We cooperated together for many years. (**Edit**: While this sentence is acceptable, it can be objectionable, see comment below.)

Similar to:

- 我們 在一起生活 很多年了 = 我們 生活在一起 很多年了

Comment: Are you sure you can move 在一起 to after 合作？ I just asked a couple of people, who both said no. I did find this sentence: 愿我们永远合作在一起！

Comment: Positively yes. There is a very slight difference, "我們在一起" = "Together, we", here "together" emphasizes "we"; "合作在一起" = "corporate together", here "together" emphasizes "corporate". Overall, the reverse in position does not make much difference.

Comment: @pedroski Agreed with you; I would also say no. r13 is likely not a native speaker. I've seen him often committing to mistakes no native speakers will.

Comment: @ALife Not all, or only, Chinese spoke perfect "Chinese/mandarin".

Comment: As @Teng Ho pointed out in the comment to the answer AdorablePaker, "合作在一起"  can be objectionable because 合作 already implies working together, and "在一起" unnecessarily repeats the implication.

Comment: if you omit 在 in the sentence  我們生活一起很多年了 is obviously wrong, and we can agree 我們一起生活(了)很多年了 is grammatically correct